# How can I render html page of Django after the background celery task is completed

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, rabbitmq, django-celery

Problems: I am using rabbitmq server with celery

1. I need to run multiple tasks in the background. That i am able to do
2. When each task is completed, i need to render the html page, to run html page i need request object as arguement, which celery task can't access
3. By the time celery task is completed i am out of the function that is having the request object

from **future** import unicode_literals, absolute_import
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from celDemo.celery import app
    import time
    from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
    # Create your views here.

```
dictionary = {}
msg = "Hello!"

def testing(request):

    print 'In 1st page:'
    return render(request,'index.html')

def testcelery(request):

    print 'In testcelery'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'On click event'
        value = str(request.POST['variable'])
        print request
        dictionary[value] = request
        print dictionary[value]
        try:
            make_wait.delay(value)
            return render(request,'index.html')
        except:
            return render(request,'nothing.html')

@app.task
def make_wait(value):
    print dictionary
    print msg
    print 'Started sleeping :)'
    actual2()
    print 'Slept :D'
    #request = dictionary[value]
    print value
    print 'before initiaing the request'
    return render('nothing.html')
    print 'after initiating the request'
    #return value


def actual2():
    result = actual()
    return result


def actual():
    time.sleep(25)
    return 'slept :D'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to get the contents of `nothing.html` before actually making the POST request. Replace the body with the contents of `nothing.html` fetched and then, make the POST request which will return the contents of `index.html`. Replace the body with the final html of `index.html` received.

Example code:

```
// js
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: 'url_to_get_nothing_html',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      $('body').html(data);
      $.ajax({
        url: 'url_to_index_html',
        type: 'POST',
        data: <data>,
        success: function(data) {
          $('body').html(data);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin. But my problem is                           make_wait.delay(value)
return render(request,'index.html') # i am not able to return this render page because i am in background process. I am not able to understand how ajax will help me out. All i need is i need to access main process variables and i want to return the Html page on browser

Comment: @SBNAB after the celery process gets over, return the contents of `index.html` which you can replace in your page, rather than `return render ...`

Comment: Yes. Make an ajax call.