# Python Flask Executor | How to pass results from a background task to a currently active html page

Tags: python, flask

To setup a simple html front-end and python flask back-

1. Create a html script (index.html) and save D:\Projects\test_backgroundtask\templates\views

```html
<html>
    <section>
      <div>
        <h>Test background task</h>
      </div>
    </section>
</html>
```

2. Create a python script and save D:\Projects\test_backgroundtask:

Code

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    
        
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def index():
        return render_template('views/index.html')
    
    @app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
    def post():
        return "recived: {}".format(request.form)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run( port = '5004')
```

To create a background task, flask has a package called flask_executor
Updated python script using excutor to create a background

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    import pandas as pd
    from flask_executor import Executor
    global input_val
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    def background_task_func(input_val):
        if input_val==1:
            data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}  
            test_val= pd.DataFrame(data)
        print(test_val)
        
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def index():
        global input_val
        input_val=1
        executor.submit(background_task_func,input_val)
        return render_template('views/index.html')
    
    @app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
    def post():
        return "recived: {}".format(request.form)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        executor = Executor(app)
        app.run( port = '5004')
```

Required Output:

**Once the results are completed, the table containing test_val should be displayed.**

**NB: the html page index.html is currently being viewed by the user and it has other tables already displayed. The user is also interacting with other buttons on this page.**

Additional Info

NB: I use Django within `<script>...</script>` in my html script.

An example of how I used it to toggle a table or button:

```
  <script>
    function myFunctionDemoFeat() {
      var x = document.getElementById("demofeatDIV");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: I am currently confused on how to pass test_val to index.html. Suggestions around this will be much appreciate. I will be able follow through from this point onwards.

Comment: I have simplified the desired output above.

Comment: I have example using celery but have not come across one with using flask executor, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922876/how-can-i-render-html-page-of-django-after-the-background-celery-task-is-complet . This can be a starting point.

Comment: Its appears that they call return render(..) again, in the function where the new values are generated. Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python script

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
from flask_executor import Executor
global input_val
global test_val
app = Flask(__name__)

def background_task_func(input_val):
    global test_val
    data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}  
    test_val= pd.DataFrame(data)
    if test_val.shape[0]>1:
        print(test_val)
        return render_template('views/index.html',tables=[test_val.to_html(classes='data')])
    
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    executor.submit(background_task_func,input_val)
    return render_template('views/index.html',tables=[test_val.to_html(classes='data')])

@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    return "recived: {}".format(request.form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data ={'Name': [], 'Age': []}  
    test_val= pd.DataFrame(data)
    input_val=1
    executor = Executor(app)
    
    app.run( port = '5004')
```

Html code

```
<html>
    <section>
      <div>
        <h>Test background task</h>
      </div>
      
      <div id="demofeatDIV" class="w3-container">
        <table class="w3-table-all w3-tiny">
            <tbody>
            <tr><th>Results</th></tr>
            {% for table in tables %}
                 {{ table|safe }}
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
       </table>
       <br>
     </div> 
    </section>
</html>
```

For a simple test example , this method will be fine. However, if there are other data being displayed, the disadvantage of using this method is that I need to refresh the entire page, this results in reloading the previous tables. The alternative solution is to use sockets. My solution in [Flask socketio | Emitting a pandas dataframe from a background task using Flask executor to an Html script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68411571/flask-socketio-emitting-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-background-task-using-flask) resolve this issue.

Comment: To create the table from a dataframe, I referred to the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52644035/how-to-show-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-existing-flask-html-table